# Want to delete SharePoint 2003 Site Collections and sites based on Input File

Tags: powershell, stsadm, 2003

Can you one please provide a sample to script to delete Sitecollection and subsites based on Input file in SharePoint 2003.

Thanks in Advance,
Phani

Comment: Can you please provide some more details about your requirement, is you want to delete the site collection and subsite based on the text file or excel file ? are you using SharePoint 2003 or 2013?

Comment: Want to delete the sitecollections and sub sites in SharePoint 2003 using csv file or text file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/93728)

Answer (score 1):

Bit of archaeology here. You will need to use stsadm to run it.

Use this command in the script.

```
$Sites = Get-Content -Path C:\SitesToDelete.csv
ForEach ($s in $Sites)
{
stsadm -o deletesite -url $s
}
```

You can use PowerShell to script it with your input but remember to use stsadm to interact with SP2003.

You might need to set up stsadm environment path or navigate to correct folder before execution. 
REF: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepointcomic/2008/08/06/stsadm-path-access-stsadm-at-anytime-in-command-prompt/